# Count repeating element sequence in an unsorted array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sequence

I need a function that receives an arrayList and returns a new arrayList of Integers with the same size. His elements will represent the number of duplicates sequences (number of appearance) of the value in index i in the original array.

1 single appearance will also be counted as a sequence.
For example: arr [*1, 1*, 0, *1*] -> the element '1' appears 2 times.

- Input: It doesn't have to be a sorted array.
- Keep the content of the array as it is in the end of the process.
- The function should be written in Java.

Example of the function:

arr [3,0,1,2,1,1,1,3] ▪︎ Input: (arr) ▪︎ Output: newArray [2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2]
because '3' appears 2 times in a sequence, '0' appears 1 time, etc...

arr [1,0,1,2,1,3] ▪︎ Input: (arr) ▪︎ Output: newArray [3,1,3,1,3,1]

arr [1,0,0,2,1,3,0] ▪︎ Input: (arr) ▪︎ Output: newArray [2,2,2,1,2,1,2]

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Please post what you currently have, and what errors you are specifically receiving. StackOverflow is meant to answer programming questions, not do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can in do this O(n) time complexity :

step 1  take a variable "prev" to check the previous element initailze it to false/0.
step 2 move through array whenever you found element to check (say x) then increment count if prev is false otherwise move forward in array.

Comment: Can you write the function please?

Answer (score 0):

This task is similar to common counting frequencies of the elements in the array/list, however, adjacent elements (subsequences) should be counted as 1.  That is, when counting frequencies the delta is 0 if the previous element is the same as the current one.

To resolve this task using Java Stream, we need to implement:

- `Collector` class to accumulate the final value and the list of indexes, including `merge` method to add indexes and the frequency.

```java
static class CollectorList {
    int sum;
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public CollectorList(List<Integer> h) {
        this.indexes.add(h.get(0));
        this.sum += h.get(1);
    }
    
    public CollectorList merge(CollectorList next) {
        this.sum += next.sum;
        this.indexes.addAll(next.indexes);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the method to get list of custom frequencies can be implemented as follows:

```java
public static List<Integer> getFrequencyList(int ... arr) {
    return new ArrayList<>(
        IntStream.range(0, arr.length)  // stream of indexes
                 .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(
                     arr[i],            // key: current element
                     Arrays.asList(i, i > 0 && arr[i] == arr[i - 1] ? 0 : 1))) // store index and delta
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     Map.Entry::getKey, // for array elements
                     e -> new CollectorList(e.getValue()), // init collector of helper 
                     CollectorList::merge   // and merge
                 ))
                 .values() // get Collection<CollectorList>
                 .stream() // convert CollectorList back to index -> frequency
                 .flatMap(c -> c.indexes.stream().map(i -> Map.entry(i, c.sum)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     Map.Entry::getKey, 
                     Map.Entry::getValue, 
                     (i1, i2) -> i1, TreeMap::new // sort by index
                 ))
                 .values() // frequencies by index
        );
}
```

The code above uses Java 9 [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) for brevity, it may be replaced with constructing [`new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) if Java 8 compatibility is needed.

Tests:

```
int[][] tests = {
    {},
    {0},
    {1,2,1,2,1,3,1},
    {1,1,0,1},
    {3,0,1,2,1,1,1,3},
    {1,0,1,2,1,3},
    {1,0,0,2,1,3,0}
};
for (int[] arr : tests) {
    List<Integer> result = getFrequencyList(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + " -> " + result);
}
```

Output

```
[] -> []
[0] -> [1]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1] -> [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4]
[1, 1, 0, 1] -> [2, 2, 1, 2]
[3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3] -> [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3] -> [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0] -> [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: That looks promising. Thank you! but is there a way to do it without having to create 2 classes? that would be even greater.

Comment: `Helper` class could be replaced with a list (e.g. `Arrays.asList(i, i > 0 && arr[i] == arr[i - 1] ? 0 : 1))`) or array, but `Collector` class would be needed anyway to encapsulate counting of frequency and maintain a list of indexes.